# Which ffmpeg command allow me to record sound?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` can be installed through termux by installing the package `mpv`:

```
$ apt-get install mpv
```

Now, on linux, I record sound with the command

```
 ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0 recording.mp3
```

This commnand does not work on android for me. What would be the right `-f` flag argument?

**What is the ffmpeg command to record sound from the terminal on android?**

Comment: Does this help? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skvalex.alsamixer (you need to be rooted, and I've never needed it, so I can't say whether it works, hence a comment instead of an answer).

Comment: The above is actually meant to work with CallRecorder, but it's not entirely impossible that ffmpeg recognises it, once it's installed and configured